# How to replace such substring in shell?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to replace substring in oldstring by new substring in linux shell:

old string may be one line of these:

```
-i eth0 -a abc -w a.pcap host 10.10.10.10
-i eth0 -a abc -w   a.pcap host 10.10.10.10
```

substring is one of these:

```
-w a.pcap
-w  a.pcap
```

new substring, '/home/test/test' is defined by 'PWD' in shell:

```
-w /home/test/test/a.pcap
```

so the new string is:

```
-i eth0 -a abc -w /home/test/test/a.pcap host 10.10.10.10
```

I don't know how to do this, as I have write a script like this, but this if 'a.pcap' change to 'e', the '-i eth' will be replace into '-i /home/test/test/eth'.

```
PWD=`pwd`
PARAM="$@"
OLD_W_PATH=
NEW_W_PATH=

process_w()
{
    if [ -z "$1" ]
    then
        echo "empty -w path param."
        exit -1
    else
        if [[ $1 == /*  ]]
        then
            # this is absolute path
            NEW_W_PATH=$1
        else
            NEW_W_PATH="${PWD}""/""$1"
        fi
    fi
}

while getopts "i:d:p:w:" arg; do
    case $arg in
        h | --help)
            echo "ovs-dump -i dpdkb2 [-d in] [-p tcp] [host 192.168.102.2][port 80] [-w /test.pcap]"
            exit 0
            ;;
        w )
            OLD_W_PATH=$OPTARG
            #NEW_W_PATH is set in process_w
            process_w $OPTARG
            ;;
        ?)
            ;;
    esac
done

# process PARAM
PARAM=${PARAM/$OLD_W_PATH/$NEW_W_PATH}
echo $PARAM
```

So will regular expresion in shell be better? Thank you~

Comment: In general, putting a command in a string [is a bad idea to start with](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: `PARAM="$@"`, in particular, introduces a huge set of bugs. You get the same value if you started with `"first word" "second word"` or `"first" "word" "second" "word"` or `first word second word`.

Comment: And `$PWD` is **always** the current working directory, by default, out-of-the-box -- using it is actually much more efficient than calling `$(pwd)`, which spawns a subshell (a separate UNIX process forked off from your shell). There's absolutely no reason to assign to it directly.

Comment: (Also, avoid all-caps names for your own variables -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html; all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the OS or shell, whereas lowercase variable names are reserved for application use and guaranteed not to conflict with the system. `PWD` is one of these variable names with meaning to the system -- see `man bash` for details).

Comment: If you're really only adding paths to `a.pcap`, you could do `newPath="/home/test/test"; sed "s@a.pcap@$newPath/a.pcap@" file > newFile`. Depending on your OS, the `-i` option can avoid creating `newFile`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to transform your command into a string at all -- it starts out as an array; *keep* it as an array.

```
#!/bin/bash

# create an empty array called "args"
args=( )

canonicalize() {
  case $1 in
    /*) printf '%s\n' "${PWD}/$1"
    *)  printf '%s\n' "$1"
  esac
}

while (( $# )); do
  case $1 in
    # if $1 is -w, then we canonicalize the path and shift a second argument off
    -w) args+=( -w "$(canonicalize "$2")" ); shift;;

    # other arguments get copied as-is
    *)  args+=( "$1" ) ;;
  esac
  shift
done

# copy that updated array back to "$@"
set -- "${args[@]}"
```